# Active Learning Bayes Learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, active-learning

[image]

How was equation (1) derived. I am familiar with MAP but I cannot understand how this equation was derived using Bayes rule. It seems that in the Likelihood part we only consider the new training point and not initial data $D_{0}$. Can some prove that the given expression is correct?